# Tensorflow model can only achieve good results on one computer, fails everywhere else

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a TensorFlow/Keras model that I am training on a synthetic classification task.

When training the model using my laptop, the model achieves 99.9% accuracy and loss values around 1e-8.

However, when I train the model on a different machine, the accuracy plateaus at 80% and the loss is stuck at 3e-1. I have reproduced the failure on my own server and Google Colab.

Now, since the issue appears to be that my laptop is configured differently, I am trying to find out what this difference is.

I have made sure that on both machines:

- Python version is 3.7
- Nvidia driver is 460.x.x
- CUDA version is 11.2
- Tensorflow version is 2.4 and is installed from pip
- Numpy version is 1.19.5
- Scipy version is 1.4.1

The laptop has an i7-7700HQ and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile.
The server has a Xeon Silver 4116 and several GPUs: TITAN Xp, TITAN V, GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER, TITAN V (I have tried all of them).

The problem happens both on CPU and GPU. Precision is set to float32 in all cases.
The code that is being run is **exactly** the same.

I cannot share the code, but I can say that it uses `tf.math.segment_sum` which is a non-deterministic op (I don't know if it may help).

I am at a complete loss here. I have tried looking at every possible discrepancy between the two configurations, but I could not find any. The fact that this issue happens also on CPU is what really blows my mind.

What could the problem be?

I hope this qualifies as a programming question since it's related to TensorFlow specifically. If not, I apologize in advance and will ask elsewhere.

Thanks

Comment: this happens with CPU also setting ALL the seeds, is it true?

Comment: is batch_size the same ? It should probably differ for CPU and GPU. And what do you mean saying that `tf.gather` is non-deterministic ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani yes, it happens regardless of the seed.

Comment: @Andrey results are the same on GPU and CPU on the same machine. Also, I made a mistake about tf.gather (i got confused with tf.scatter_nd), I have fixed it now.

Comment: pytorch has a setting for cudnn determinism -- is there something similar for TF?

Comment: @JohnStud yes, it is possible to set a flag for cuDNN determinism but that doesn't change the results. Also the issue happens also on CPU

Comment: @DanieleGrattarola with my last 5 cents I can suggest you try a very basic model on your pc and on your server/colab with CPU... if the results are the same this means that the config is ok and the operations in your model are not deterministic, otherwise, it's the config different

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I have spent all day debugging, no luck. Using the same model on a different task gives comparable results on both machines, so it's likely not an issue of configuration. It may have  something to do with the data, but it's not significantly different from the other task that I have tried.

Comment: Well if the data is different, you will get different results. Particularly as dimensionality increases, optimizing will get more and more varied.

Comment: @JohnStud the different results that I get are one the same data. I was only mentioning that, when I test a similar model on a different dataset, the results that I get on the two computers are the same. So this appears to be a data-related problem, although I fail to see how.